# CS50.dev Terminal Language

Tags: python, github, cs50

I'm currently doing edx's cs50 course, and the IDE booted up in Spanish. I found the option to change the IDE's language to English, but the terminal is still showing error codes and everything else in Spanish. Does someone know if there's a command to change the terminal's language?

I already tried going into the terminal's settings, but searching for "language" or "idioma" (Spanish for language) doesn't show any options related to the display language, only showing coding language related settings.

Comment: What operating system are you using and what are the localization settings?

Comment: This seems more suitable for [cs50.se]. I suggest migration.

Answer (score 0):

In the CS50 IDE, you can change the terminal language by changing the LANG environment variable. Open a terminal and execute the following command:

> Export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

This command sets up the LANG environment variable to use the English language with UTF-8 encoding. It should set the language of terminal messages and error codes to English. If you're using a different language, simply change en_US with the corresponding language code, such as es_ES for Spanish.

Keep in mind that this change is only temporary and will have an impact on the current terminal session. In order to make it permanent, add the following command to your shell profile file

> (e.g., ~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_profile, or ~/.zshrc).

After running the command, you may need to restart the terminal or open a new terminal window for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).